# ant conditional import

Tags: ant

Is it possible to import a file in ant's build.xml if a property is set, if not then don't import it.

Is there a way OTHER THAN using ant-contrib if task.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
For example:

```
<target name="importFile" depends="myProperty.check" if="myPropertyIsSet">
    <echo>Import my file here</echo>
</target>

<target name="myTarget.check">
    <condition property="myPropertyIsSet">
        <and>
            <!-- Conditions to check if my property is set. -->
        </and>
    </condition>
</target>
```

Available conditions are described in [Apache Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html).

Comment: That did not work. As of ant 1.7 you cannot use import inside a target. It has to be a top level task

Comment: Ouch, my fault. Also, is optional attribute of import task not enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question but since Ant 1.9.1 you can use the "if"-attribute to do conditional imports:

```xml
<project name="cond-import" basedir="." xmlns:if="ant:if">
  <condition property="script-exists">
    <available file="other-ant-script.xml"/>
  </condition>
  <include if:set="script-exists" file="other-ant-script.xml"/>
</project>
```